# Wamp server cant enable/disable modules (for apache)

Tags: apache, module, localhost, wamp

I cant enable APACHE modules on WAMP-Server. 
After i click the module name (which is not-checked), then server restarts, but when i go to modules, then module is not still enabled.

I even manually opened httpd.conf and enabled module, restarted server, but module is not still enabled!

Has anyone faced similar problem ? what's solution?

Comment: Are you running WAMPServer As an administrator. Unless you are this will happen

Comment: @RiggsFolly :) still doesnt help. However, convert your comment into answer, they are good tips, i will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of tips.

- WAMPServer must be installed as an Administrator so when you launch the install `right click the .exe` and select "Run as Administrator"
- WAMPServer must also be `Run As Administrator`
- When you attempt to include or exclude a new Apache or PHP extension, WAMPserver will attempt to restart Apache so the changes takes effect. If the changes do not show up, it may just be that the menu just skipped a beat, then try a refresh by doing

  `right click wampmanager -> refresh`

If you install WAMPServer using the "Run as Administrator" but attempt to run WAMPServer without using the "Run As Administrator" it will not have the rights to amend some of its own files. This can cause problems like this one, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

solution seemed to `EXIT` WampServer, then modify `httpd.conf` manually, and starting Wamp again.

Answer (score 0):

I has this same issue (drove me crazy for a while!), and in my case I had to increase the memory_limit setting in php.ini (make sure it's the right one - open from Wampmanager - it's actually in the apache folder). I set it to 512M and it worked on 2 of the 3 servers I was having issues with.

For the other one I has to add this line:
   ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
to the top of file: 
   [drive]/[wamprootfolder]/scripts/refresh.php
And then run the Refresh from Wampmanager (right-click the icon). DON'T FORGET TO COMMENT IT OUT/REMOVE THE LINE ONCE IT COMPLETES. This disables the limit which can cause issues if it loads a script with a memory leak, etc.

The problem is that the refresh.php script is supposed to automatically update the wampmanager.ini file (found in [wamprootfolder]) after each change, or when you run it from Wampmanager itself. With the memory setting too low, it caused the function to exit without changing the .ini file, which is why you keep seeing the same settings, version # (after an update), etc.

To test, you can load the default wamp homepage in a browser to confirm version, and then click on phpinfo() to verify what modules, etc. are actually loading. OR just look at the modified date of your wampmanager.ini file!

Once it's working right, your wampmanager.ini should update itself when you run the Refresh (or make a change).